# Android - Reduce ART Memory Usage

Tags: java, android, memory, memory-management

I'm writing an application targeting minSDK 15; however, when it's running on ART, the memory usage shoots up. (3x or more)

```
  Device    Android    Memory Usage
HTC One X+   4.1.1       23.32 MB
Xperia S     4.1.1       29.78 MB
Nexus 6      5.0.0       90.27 MB
```

Is there an easy way to reduce memory usage for applications running ART? I was thinking that making two separate builds, one targeting minSDK 15, and one targeting minSDK 20 would help with this, but no.

Thanks for your time and help.